# Паттерн программирования "Decorator"

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть учебное задание:

> Определить спецификации классов для представления графических
>   манипуляторов геометрических свойств (положение, размер) в редакторе
>   векторной графики.

И есть три паттерна: композит, декоратор, и прокси. Мне кажется, что тут именно декоратор.

Реализовать его надо с "заглушками", т.е. не графически.

И я столкнулся с проблемой, что чистым декоратором я его не могу реализовать, так как функции изменения размера и положения требуют передаваемых значений.

```
public interface Shape {
public void draw();
public void setX(int x);
public void setY(int y);
public void setLength(int length);
public void setHeight(int height);
public void changePosition(int x, int y);
public void changeSize(int length, int height);
}
```

Потомки, которые наследуют Шейп тоже имеют функции `changePosition(int x, int y)` и `changeSize(int length, int height)`, и мне кажется, что это не совсем правильно. Может быть я выбрал не тот паттерн?

Comment: что-то я так и не понял, что надо сделать, что уже сделано, и что, собственно, не нравится?

Comment: Composite лучше. Так вы сможете объединять объекты в группы и манипулировать с группами как с графическими объектами, вызывая изменение размеров для всех дочерних элементов.

Comment: @grundy не нравится то что декоратор получается как бы не декоратор.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev но ведь декоратор расширяет функционал

Comment: @thundermind, и? Методы изменения размера и положения графических объектов являются неотъемлемой частью их сущности. Что-то мне подсказывает, что тут не нужно ничего расширять

Comment: @thundermind, а что касается _Композита_ то и он может быть избыточен в данном случае. Немного подумав, я не очень представляю зачем в рамках указанной задачи нужны перечисленные паттерны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Декоратор никак не связан с тем, что потомки имеют свои функции.

И это тоже ошибочное утверждение:

> чистым декоратором я его не могу реализовать, так как функции
>   изменения размера и положения требуют передаваемых значений.

Декоратор на указанный интерфейс будет выглядеть так:

```
public class ShapeWrapper implements Shape {
  private Shape original;

  public void draw() {
    original.draw();
  }

  public void setX(int x) {
    //добавляем свой код, например
    original.setX(x); //передаем вызов "настоящему" Shape'у
    //добавляем свой код, например
  }

  ...

  public void changeSize(int length, int height) {
    original.changeSize(length, height);
  }

  //Обязательно нужен конструктор декоратора из объекта Shape
  public ShapeWrapper(Shape original) {
    this.original = original;
  }
}
```

В каждый метод мы можем добавить наш код до или после передачи вызова объекту original, в этом и заключается смысл декоратора. Если это не то, что нужно, этот паттерн вам не подходит.